# When using Maatwebsite\Excel in laravel project getting Could not open file "" for writing error

Tags: excel, laravel

I want to generate an excel sheet with custom array in laraval. So I have used "Maatwebsite\Excel" package.
Below is my export function,

```
public function export(){
    $users = [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Hardik',
            'email' => 'hardik@gmail.com'
        ],
        [
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'Vimal',
            'email' => 'vimal@gmail.com'
        ],
        [
            'id' => 3,
            'name' => 'Harshad',
            'email' => 'harshad@gmail.com'
        ]
    ];
      
    return Excel::download(new RequestExport($users), 'users.xlsx');
}
```

Here is my RequestExport class,

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class RequestExport implements FromCollection
{
    protected $data;
  
    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }
  
    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function collection()
    {
        return collect($this->data);
    }
  
    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function headings() :array
    {
        return [
            'ID',
            'Name',
            'Email',
        ];
    }
}
```

When calling the export function always getting this error,
[image]

Someone please help me to solve this.

Comment: Try with clearing cache by `php artisan optimize:clear` and `php artisan config:cache`. Because from your given details there is not an issue in both file code. Also you can check you have import Excel class or not in files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with clearing cache by `php artisan optimize:clear` and `php artisan config:cache`

Also you can recheck you have `import Excel:class` in files.